# What does `foo[x]` mean in this context?

Tags: javascript

I have a pretty standard Javascript loop below but am having a hard time trying to understand parts of it and would love an explenaiton as to what these parts of the code do and how they work.

```
var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];
var max = 0;
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i] > max){
        max = numbers[i];
    }
}
alert(max);
```

My main problem is understanding the following:

```
numbers[i]
```

What does this mean and how does it exist in this manner?

I thought that [x] was accesing a part of an array if so how and where is the array built?

Comment: `var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];` is your Array. `[]` is an accessor for the array, i.e `numbers[0]` would return `3`.

Comment: I recommend to read some JavaScript introduction, for example the [MDN  JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];
```

This initializes an array with the members `3,345,28,90,102`, so 5 items in total.

```
var max = 0;
```

Init maximum to zero. Assuming, that all numbers are non-negative.

```
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
```

Run through all items of the array `numbers`.

```
    if(numbers[i] > max){
```

If we got a number larger than our current maximum ...

```
        max = numbers[i];
```

... adjust our maximum to that number.

```
    }
}

alert(max);
```

Output the maxium

Answer (score 6):

```
var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];
```

is a shorthand for

```
var numbers = new Array(3,345,28,90,102);
```

So that is the story of how `numbers` came to be an array

`numbers[x]` accesses the `x`th (0-indexed) element in the array. For example `numbers[0]` returns the first item which is `3`.

---

As a bonus, the whole snippet can be replaced with:

```
var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];
```

this code is creating an integer array with values 3,345, 28 and so on.

to access array element you can use : (array starts from 0 index)

```
numbers[0] is 3
numbers[1] is 345
numbers[2] is 28
```

now in this code a var i is used to iterate through whole array till 'numbers.length' and accessing all values using numbers[i]. while loop will iterate through i=0  to i = 5(length of array).

```
if(numbers[i] > max){
    max = numbers[i];
}
```

this condition is trying to find the maximum number from the array. and set it in variable max.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [3,345,28,90,102];
```

This is where the array is 'built' (declared).

The other way you could have done it was to declare a `new Array()` and then populate the elements one by one.